# Rake task with minitest-spec-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task, minitest

I have been using the minitest-rails gem, and everything works great when I run:

```
  rake minitest:models
```

However, I recently switched to the minitest-spec-rails gem, and when I run that same command I get this error:

```
 "Don't know how to build task 'minitest:models'"
```

Anyone know what the difference (in this regard) is between the two gems?

This is my rake file (that works with rake minitest:models)

```
require "rake/testtask"

Rake::TestTask.new(:test => "db:test:prepare") do |t| 
  t.libs << "test"
  t.pattern = "test/**/*_test.rb"
end

task :default => :test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minitest-spec-rails gem only enables the minitest spec DSL in your rails tests. So you will have to use the standard test rake tasks. To test just the files under test/models, you will need to create your own rake task.

The minitest-rails gem enables the spec DSL, as well as provides generators that use the spec DSL, and additional rake tasks. It can help bridge the gap between Rails 3 and 4.

Comment: So, either gem provides MiniTest::Spec.  Its confusing to know which is best. Your gem is far more popular (judging from downloads).
So, for using MiniTest::Spec and sliding right in to rails 4...either gem will work?  If the answer is yes, then I will go back to using minitest-rails.  I only switched two days ago just to check it out, due to some article I read.  Your ping pong photo is enough to keep me on your gem...

Comment: One last question, ..why do some prefer mintest-spec-rails?

Comment: Both will enable the spec DSL in Rails. We've briefly discussed merging the gems, but there are no plans to do that ATM.